# Is possible to run CouchDB without installation from shell?

Tags: mongodb, shell, couchdb

I want to try CouchDB in my application, but I couldn't find how to run this without installation from linux shell.

When I Worked with MongoDB, I used following exetutable files (for example mongod to run server) to run it

```
./mongo
```

but I found only examples which are using installed CouchDB.

Is there any choice how to run CouchDB server without installation?

**EDIT:** I look for simple solution similar to running MongoDB features as above, if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to try out CouchDB is to use a DBaaS solution such as [Cloudant](http://www.cloudant.com) or [Iriscouch](http://www.iriscouch.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to **try** Apache CouchDB is to run it as a Docker container.

as daemon:

```
docker run -p 5984:5984 --name couchdb -d couchdb
```

or interactive:

```
docker run -it -p 5984:5984 --name couchdb couchdb
****************************************************
WARNING: CouchDB is running in Admin Party mode.
     This will allow anyone with access to the
     CouchDB port to access your database. In
     Docker's default configuration, this is
     effectively any other container on the same
     system.
     Use "-e COUCHDB_USER=admin -e COUCHDB_PASSWORD=password"
     to set it in "docker run".
****************************************************
Apache CouchDB 1.6.1 (LogLevel=info) is starting.
Apache CouchDB has started. Time to relax.
[info] [<0.32.0>] Apache CouchDB has started on http://0.0.0.0:5984/
```

references:

https://hub.docker.com/_/couchdb/

https://github.com/apache/couchdb-docker